# condition based cumulative count within a groupby

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, lets say as follows
df.head(10)

```
Acctid       Disposition
1             Unsuccessful
2             Unsuccessful
3             successful
1             Unsuccessful
2             Unsuccessful
2             Successful
1             Successful
```

The result after groupby with acctid which I want is as follows in pandas is as follows

```
Acctid    Attempts before Successful
1           2
2           2
3           1
```

I simply want the number of unsuccessful attempts before a successful attempt within a groupby of a dataframe.In the event Successful for an acctid comes first,it is market as 1.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Just post how first five rows and then explain how do you want that?

Comment: After an Acctid is successful are there any more entries for it? For example, could there be an Unsuccessful entry for Acctid 3 after its already successful?

Comment: Hi there @Swarnendu Bhattacharya, it might be helpful if you provided a minimally reproducible example in terms of the code you've tried as well.

Comment: how its 1 for 3 ? you are saying attempt before sucessful. Was'nt this should be 0 ?

Comment: After successful an acctid can still have unsuccessfulattempts

Comment: I dont want the counter of unsuccessful attempts,I want the counter of unsuccessful attempts before the 1st Successful attempt is present for an account id,no matter how many unsuccessful attempts it has after the 1st successful attempt

Answer (score 0):

If after an Acctid is successful there is no more entries, the following code should give you what you're looking for.

```
df['Counter'] = np.where(df['Disposition'] == 'Unsuccessful',1,0)
df.groupby('Acctid')['Counter'].sum()
```

Comment: After successful an acctid can still have unsuccessfulattempts-True

Comment: I dont want the counter of unsuccessful attempts,I want the counter of unsuccessful attempts before the 1st Successful attempt is present for an account id,no matter how many unsuccessful attempts it has after the 1st successful attempt